# Make python script to run forever on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a python script that basically runs forever and checks a webpage every second and notifies me if any value changes. I placed it on an AWS EC2 instance and ran it through ssh. The script was running fine when I checked after half an hour or so after I started it.

The problem is that after a few hours when I checked again, the ssh had closed. When I logged back in, there was no program running. I checked all running processes and nothing was running.

Can anyone teach me how to make it run forever (or until I stop it) on AWS EC2 instances? Thanks a lot.

---

Edit: I used the Java SSH Client provided by AWS to run the script

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `Linux screen`.Linux screen tool can not only save you from disconnection disasters, but it also can increase your productivity by using multiple windows within one SSH session.
To install:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Start a new session:

```
screen -S <screen_name>
```

Run your process as you run it in the screen session. If you want to back to your main terminal press key shortcut `ctrl+a+d`. And also view the screen by typing,

```
screen -r <screen_name>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this is the most easiest and the best solution and good thing is screen comes built in installed on ubuntu18.04

Comment: Thank you. I have seen and tried so many WRONG answers until now. This actually worled. Thanks for the simple and easy explanation.

Answer (score 17):

You can run the program using the nohup command, so that even when the SSH session closes your program continues running.

Eg: `nohup python yourscriptname.py &`

For more info you can check the man page for it using
`man nohup`.